# IE7/8 Scale background image 100% of the width of its container

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, css

I am working on an image slider that scales an image. Of course this works fine in all browsers included IE9+ but for IE7/8 it seems to scale the image to fit the containers height and not the width...

I am using the following CSS code to scale the images.

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../files/slideshow/3.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')"
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../files/slideshow/3.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
```

I was curious if anyone knew of a way to make this scale by the width of the container instead of the height using either CSS or JavaScript?

You can view it here http://kearsargefire.org/

Comment: `width: 100%; height: auto;` usually does it for me.

Comment: The problem is once I add `height:auto;` no image appears

Comment: What is an "unpaid professional", anyway?

Comment: Assuming you're using `background-size` for other browsers, you could use a polyfill like [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) that adds support for CSS background-size to older IE versions.

Comment: CSS3Pie Supports backgroundsize! That is amazing. Ill have to go check it out.

Comment: @Blazemonger I believe they mean "Trained Volunteers"

Comment: There's also [this polyfill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill) which is specific to `background-size`.

Answer (score 0):

Check it...

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

**HTML**

```
<img src="images/bg.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
```

**CSS**

```
#bg { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; }
.bgwidth { width: 100%; }
.bgheight { height: 100%; }
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(window).load(function() {    

        var theWindow        = $(window),
            $bg              = $("#bg"),
            aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

        function resizeBg() {

                if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
                    $bg
                        .removeClass()
                        .addClass('bgheight');
                } else {
                    $bg
                        .removeClass()
                        .addClass('bgwidth');
                }

        }

        theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");

});
```

Adjust the code for instead of "$(window)" to be your container.